# PHP Form with required fields

Tags: php, mysql

I want to creat a form which can connect to mysql and can insert records which I have done. But now I want to make some fields mandatory, username and car for example. Also showing the error field as required or "name cannot have numbers". Stuff like that. I am unable to figure it out.

Some help please:

I have index.html

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Nume: <input type="text" name="name"><span class="error">* <?php echo $error;?></span><br>
Prenume: <input type="text" name="prenume"><br>
Masina: <input type="radio" name="masina" value="vito"> (Vito)
<input type="radio" name="masina" value="skoda"> (Skoda)
<input type="radio" name="masina" value="skoda2"> (Skoda)
<input type="radio" name="masina" value="audi"> (Audi)<br><br>

Data: <input type="date" name="data"/><br>
Ora: <input type="time" name="ora"/><br>


Destinatie:<input type="text" name="destinatie"><br>

KM la iesire: <input type="text" name="kmiesire"><br>
KM la intrare: <input type="text" name="kmintrare"><br>

<input type="submit">
```

and Insert.php

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

$order = "INSERT INTO data_employees
            (name, prenume, masina, data, ora, destinatie, kmiesire, kmintrare)
            VALUES 
            ('$_POST[name]',
            '$_POST[prenume]',
            '$_POST[masina]','$_POST[data]','$_POST[ora]','$_POST[destinatie]',
            '$_POST[kmiesire]','$_POST[kmintrare]'
            )";

if (mysqli_query($con,$order)){
    header('Location: index.html');
}else{
    echo("Input data is fail");
}

?>
```

Comment: Read about post and get first. Use something like if !isset...

Comment: Hey there, [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).  Never thought I'd see you here!

Comment: use jquery validation plugin and in php just check all values.

Answer (score 1):

you have to check rules before the query...

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])){
   echo "Name Required";
}
elseif(bla bla){
  echo "something"
}
else {
   // your query....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start checking with ,

```
    if($_POST) {
          if(isset($_POST['name'])!='') {
               echo 'your error message';
          }else if (isset($_POST['prenume'])!='') {
               echo 'your error message';
          }.....

          else 
              //your insertion code (query)
    }
```

And also you can check with `@` ,`empty`  like `isset` .

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that POST values are not empty then there is no injected code to prevent injection attacks.

You should take a look to PDO PHP. It will be more safer than mysql low-level functions and more easy to use.